# JAVA parsing inner JSON

Tags: android, json

I am trying to take "**key**" value in a JSON file. I tried many solutions but I couldn't handle this ,it constantly gives me "**at videos of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray**" error. How can I solve this. Thank you.

My JSON data;

```
{   videos: {
        results:[
                 {
                  id: "56c4ccbfc3a3680d52000610",
                  iso_639_1: "en",
                  iso_3166_1: "US",
                  key: "nIGtF3J5kn8",
                 }
               ]
            }           
}
```

My code;

```
JSONArray Movie_List = Search_Results.getJSONArray("videos");
for (int i = 0; i < Movie_List.length(); i++) 
{
       JSONObject movie = (JSONObject) Movie_List.get(i);
       JSONArray Movie_List1 = movie.getJSONArray("results");
       for (int j = 0; j < Movie_List1.length(); j++) 
       {
          JSONObject movie2 = (JSONObject) Movie_List1.get(j);
          key = movie2.getString("key");

       }
}
```

The error;
[image]

Comment: Videos is an object not an array. Results is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some like this.. Your mistake come because you try to parse  videos to `JSONArray` but it is `JSONObject`...

```
JSONObject videos = Search_Results.getJSONObject("videos");
    JSONArray result= videos.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) 
    {
           JSONObject movie = result.getJSONObject(i);
           String movieId = movie.getString("id");
    //and other values .. same way

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working now and I understand what is the proplem